# Db design relationship between n:n tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have poor skills for db design and I need some help about relations setup.
So use case is:

```
User which can be Coach or Client.
Client can have many coaches and coaches can have many clients.
Coach can create many workouts for client.
Client can also have many workouts assigned from coach.
Workout have many sets, sets have many exercises and reps etc...
```

So I created design on image.
But what make me feel that I am doing everything wrong is double keys.
In this table `client_has_coach_has_workout` I have two keys referencing n:n table and it confuses me as when I need to import data it will always have both keys from n:n table.
Any help please.
[image]

Comment: Are the Ids for `coach` and `client` known outside of the model, or are they _Identity_ columns in SQL (where the value is generated)

Comment: User and Coach/Client are 1:1 relation. Id is generated in user table.

Comment: Your model is more or less valid, but there are many different design patterns to choose from for M:N tables. Your question is a little bit ambiguous because you talk about structure vs importing data, importing data into a normalised model will usually require some form of foreign key resolution. If you are having trouble with importing then that is a different question to what you have posted here.

Comment: For assistance on how to import your data into this model you would need to post an example of your import dataset and an example query of your attempt, we can only provide first-principals suggestions on this forum but it may help explain how to use your model.

Answer (score 0):

This design can work if you want it to, but I would consider reversing the link between `coach` and `client` to `user`.

- remove `client_id` from `user`
- remove `coach_id` from `user`
- Add `user_id` as a foreign key to `client`
- Add `user_id` as a foreign key to `coach`

Ultimately yes you are correct that now there are composite keys, but this is not a problem because during importing you would always need to lookup both the `client_id` and the `coach_Id` anyway.

To simplify the model logic, you can add an arbitrary `Id` key column to `client_has_coach` then `client_has_coach_has_workout` only needs a single foreign key `client_has_coach_id` that links back to the `client_has_coach` table, this forces us to lookup the specific linking record from `client_has_coach` and helps us enforce it's existence.

If you do use a composite key, then we can generally skip the lookup for `client_has_coach` and *assume* that it already exists, but this can lead to orphaned rows or scenarios where there is no record in `client_has_coach` corresponding to a combination of keys in `client_has_coach_has_workout`.

- Composite keys work well in models where we do not need to maintain integrity between `client_has_coach` and `client_has_coach_has_workout`. But your naming conventions suggests that this is not a desirable aspect in your model.

Either way, on import of data you would need to first lookup the `coach` record, then lookup the `client` record to check for or create the record in `client_has_coach`, you would then import corresponding rows into `client_has_coach_has_workout`.